# Efficiently processing ~50 million record file in python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, lookup, latency

We have a file with about 46 million records in CSV format. Each record has about 18 fields and one of them is a 64 byte ID. We have another file with about 167K unique IDs in it. The records corresponding to the IDs needs to be yanked out. So, we have written a python program that reads the 167K IDs into an array and processes the 46 million records file checking if the ID exists in each one of the those records. Here is the snippet of the code:

```
import csv
...
csvReadHandler = csv.reader(inputFile, delimiter=chr(1))
csvWriteHandler = csv.writer(outputFile, delimiter=chr(1), lineterminator='\n')
for fieldAry in csvReadHandler:
    lineCounts['orig'] += 1
    if fieldAry[CUSTOMER_ID] not in idArray:
        csvWriteHandler.writerow(fieldAry)
        lineCounts['mod'] += 1
```

Tested the program on a small set of data, here are the processing times:

```
lines: 117929 process time: 236.388447046 sec
lines: 145390 process time: 277.075321913 sec
```

We have started running the program on the 46 million records file (which is about 13 GB size) last night ~3:00am EST, now it is around 10am EST and it is still processing!

Questions:

1. Is there a better way to process these records to improve on processing times?
2. Is python the right choice? Would awk or some other tool help?
3. I am guessing 64 byte ID look-up on 167K array in the following statement is the culprit:
    `if fieldAry[CUSTOMER_ID] not in idArray:`

Is there a better alternative?

Thank you!

Update: This is processed on an EC2 instance with EBS attached volume.

Comment: What is the type of `idArray`? Make sure it's some data structure which supports efficient tests for membership, e.g. a `set` is probably going to be a lot faster than a plain `[]` list.

Comment: How about using a Database Management System...

Comment: 1) " reads the 167K IDs into an array " ... If I understand correctly you mean list? try use set(); 2) create tmp variable for ineCounts['orig'] and lineCounts['mod'], assign them back after the loop; 3) not sure how csv.reader is implemented, if yield(for row in it) generates IO operation, maybe you can read the CSV into memory first..

Comment: This one is tricky, I've answered a similar question where the user in that case needed to check time-stamps (beginning of each line) on huge sets of data. I'll ask the same question to you, is it at all possible to get the 45 million records in a database alternative?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe idArray is an array containing 64bytes ids and it is about 167K. We will check with the set against the array. -Thanks

Comment: @SnoopyGuo counts can be ignored as they are just integer increments. May be I should have removed them from the code snippet.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala and Torxed: We will look into DB, but if in memory look-ups are taking this long, building the DB indexes for this many records and then doing an intersection is going to be helpful.

Comment: `array` isn't a native python data type. Can you tell us what `idArray`'s actual type is?

Comment: You could replace `if fieldAry[CUSTOMER_ID] not in idArray:` with `if 1:` to isolate the time it takes to check the id. That would tell you whether you have I/O or other performance bottlenecks or whether you should focus on the id check.

Comment: @tdelaney: With if 1:, huge difference. Here are the times: lines: 117929 process time: 10.4495661259 sec, lines: 145390 process time: 10.5829188824 sec.  I think ID checks are still an issue. -Thanks

Comment: @S.A Good to see it narrow down? You may want to revisit the `set` solution. Assuming what you call `array` is a `list`, it should make a dramatic difference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You <s>should</s> must use a `set` instead of a `list`; *before* the `for` loop do:

```
idArray = set(idArray)

csvReadHandler = csv.reader(inputFile, delimiter=chr(1))
csvWriteHandler = csv.writer(outputFile, delimiter=chr(1), lineterminator='\n')
for fieldAry in csvReadHandler:
    lineCounts['orig'] += 1
    if fieldAry[CUSTOMER_ID] not in idArray:
        csvWriteHandler.writerow(fieldAry)
        lineCounts['mod'] += 1
```

And see the unbelievable speed-up; you're using ***days*** worth of unnecessary processing time just because you chose the wrong data structure.

---

`in` operator with `set` has **O(1)** time complexity, whereas **O(n)** time complexity with `list`. This might sound like "not a big deal" but actually **it is the bottleneck in your script**. Even though `set` will have somewhat higher constants for that **O**. So your code is using something like 30000 more time on that single `in` operation than is necessary. If in the optimal version it'd require 30 seconds, now you spend 10 days on that single line alone.

See the following test: I generate 1 million IDs and take 10000 aside into another list - `to_remove`. I then do a `for` loop like you do, doing the `in` operation for each record:

```
import random
import timeit

all_ids = [random.randint(1, 2**63) for i in range(1000000)]
to_remove = all_ids[:10000]
random.shuffle(to_remove)
random.shuffle(all_ids)


def test_set():
    to_remove_set = set(to_remove)
    for i in all_ids:
        if i in to_remove_set:
            pass

def test_list():
    for i in all_ids:
        if i in to_remove:
            pass


print('starting')
print('testing list', timeit.timeit(test_list, number=1))
print('testing set', timeit.timeit(test_set, number=1))
```

And the results:

```
testing list 227.91903045598883
testing set 0.14897623099386692
```

It took 149 milliseconds for the `set` version; the `list` version required 228 seconds. Now these were small numbers: in your case you have 50 million input records against my 1 million; thus there you need to multiply the `testing set` time by 50: with your data set it would take about 7.5 seconds.

The list version, on the other hand, you need to multiply that time by 50 * 17 - not only are there 50 times more input records, but 17 times more records to match against. Thus we get 227 * 50 * 17 = 192950.

So your algorithm spends 2.2 days doing something that by using correct data structure can be done in 7.5 seconds. Of course this does not mean that you can scan the *whole 50 GB document in 7.5 seconds*, but it probably ain't more than 2.2 days either. So we changed from:

```
             2 days                           2.2 days 
 |reading and writing the files||------- doing id in list ------|
```

to something like

```
             2 days            7.5 seconds (doing id in set)
 |reading and writing the files||
```

Comment: Tried "set" instead of array on the same set of data. Didn't really help. Here are the processing times: lines: 117929 process time: 249.074661016 sec and lines: 145390 process time: 309.015148878 sec - Thanks

Comment: "Didn't really help?" What did happen?

Comment: "set" did improve the look-up time. We had an issue with the sample data and hence previously reported data was wrong. We have also implemented DJB's cdb look-up and that is looking good too. Additionally found that the reason for problem was a default "CPU Credit" limit on our EC2 instance. It just aggravated the whole latency issue. Just completed the run on three data sets, one using "set" lookup and the other two with cdb. There is an issue with "set" lookup and we are going through the data checks. Thanks everyone for your feedback!

Comment: Yeah I also thought about the CPU credit as well. Do note that if you loaded this into an RDBMS, then `DELETE` does not need to necessarily rewrite 13 GB, it just marks some of the rows as dead.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to speed things a bit would be to parallelize the line-processing with some distributed solution. On of the easiest would be to use multiprocessing.Pool. You should do something like this (syntax not checked):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

p = Pool(processes=4)
p.map(process_row, csvReadHandler)
```

Despite that, python is not the best language to do this kind of batch processing (mainly because writing to disk is quite slow). It is better to leave all the disk-writing management (buffering, queueing, etc...) to the linux kernel so using a bash solution would be quite better. Most efficient way would be to split the input files into chunks and simply doing an inverse grep to filter the ids.

```
for file in $list_of_splitted_files; then
  cat $file | grep -v (id1|id2|id3|...) > $file.out
done;
```

if you need to merge afterwards simply:

```
for file in $(ls *.out); then
  cat $file >> final_results.csv
done
```

Considerations:

- Don't know if doing a single grep with all the ids is more/less
  efficient than looping through all the ids and doing a single-id
  grep.
- When writing parallel solutions try to read/write to different
  files to minimize the I/O bottleneck (all threads trying to write to
  the same file) in all languages.
- Put timers on your code for each processing part. This way you'll see which part is wasting more time. I **really recommend this** because I had a similar program to write and I thought the processing part was the bottleneck (similar to your comparison with the ids vector) but in reality it was the I/O which was dragging down all the execution.

Comment: this would be a 4-fold increase at maximum, but the whole thing should be I/O bound anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Didn't have a chance to try yet because we are using the a T2 instance of EC2 and it is CPU credit limited. We are planning to spin off c4 or m4 and may be your suggestion might help us on those instances.

Answer (score 0):

i think its better to use a database to solve this problem
first create a database like MySql or anything else
then write your data from file into 2 table
and finally use a simple sql query to select rows
somthing like:
select * from table1 where id in(select ids from table2)

Answer (score 0):

Best is to use Big data approach. Something like PySpark on AWS EMR which can do batch process on the data. A decent size cluster takes around 1-2 hours to process 7 million records.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please be more detailed with your answers. Why do you recommend this solution over other ones?